# jquery and javascript functions timing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a cookie based menu which contains three options (three links). Now I want that when a user gets on the site, they must have to choose one of the three options. The user's selection may be store in a cookie so that next time when he arrives at the same site, he does not have to make the selection again and he must be directed automatically to his previous selection.

This is my code for that

```
</style>
<!-- style Develpor page ends here-->
<script src="jqery1.8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var val;

$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('.nav a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    val = $(this).index();

    if (val == 0) {

      $('#hide_main').hide();
      $('.main_BSNS').animate({
        opacity: "show",
        height: "400px"
      }, 'slow')

    } //if val==0 ends here

    else if (val == 1) {

      $('#hide_main').hide();
      $('.main_ACTNT').animate({
        opacity: "show",
        height: "400px"
      }, 'slow')

    } else if (val == 2) {

      $('#hide_main').hide();
      $('.main_devp').animate({
        opacity: "show",
        height: "400px"
      }, 'slow')

    }
  });
});



<!--cookies starts here-->
function getCookie(c_name) {
  var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (x == c_name) {
      return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie() {
  var username = getCookie("BSNS");
  if (username != null && username != "") {
    $('#hide_main').hide();
    $('.main_BSNS').animate({
      opacity: "show",
      height: "400px"
    }, 'slow')

  } else {

    username=val;
    alert(val);
    if (username != null && username != "") {
      setCookie("BSNS", username, 365);
      $('#hide_main').hide();
      $('.main_BSNS').animate({
        opacity: "show",
        height: "400px"
      }, 'slow')

    }
  }
}
<!--cookies ends here-->
</script>
```

Now function `checkCookie()` is called by body `onload="checkCookie()"` and the alert returns the value of `val` as `undefined` I know this is because the `checkCookie()` is being loaded before `document.write` but I don't know how to overcome this difficulty.

Comment: *i know this is because the checkCookie() is being loaded before document.write* ... there is no `document.write` in your code and you can define a function anytime. You only run into problems when you want to access DOM before they exist. Cookies can be accessed anytime.

Comment: there is document.ready, please check at the start of the code...its 
$(document).ready(fucntion(){
//rest of the code

});

i am talking about this document.ready

Comment: *(after formatting the code, I can actually see which functions are defined)* ... You don't seem to assign a value to `val` anywhere. If you don't do that, `val` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: and i know there is some mistake or something is missing but i am unable to figure out what is the mistake or what is missing...that is why i am here.....

Comment: yes this is the problem....val is not getting assigned....i dont know the reason....

Comment: Because you don't do it! Look, you write `var username = ...;` for example. I.e. you are assigning a value to `username`. You never write `val = ...;`. `val` does not get a value magically by itself. *You* have to assign it.

Comment: if i put username=val then will the code work????

Comment: Have you tried using debugging tools such as FireBug or built-in developer tools for Chrome or IE?

Comment: Since `val` is `undefined` it means you would assign `undefined` to `username`. You might want `val = username;` instead, but I don't know what values `username` has, so I don't know if it will make the code work. I really encourage you to read a JavaScript tutorial, variable assignment is one of most fundamental things in every language (http://eloquentjavascript.net/).

Comment: @oracle: I thought so too, but the fact that the `alert` is shown suggests otherwise. It would still be good to remove it though.

Comment: Thanks for the help Felix but kindly if you see the code i put $('.nav a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    val = $(this).index();

i think it assigns some value to "val"....but what i think is the problem is checkCookie() function is called by body onload event which would be the first event that will occur when i click on the preview....that is why val is undefined.....

Comment: You assign a value to `val` in your `.click` method, but it tries to alert/use it before anything is clicked.

Comment: Oh that's true... I must have missed that. Sorry! Then what exactly "does not work"? As BeardFist points out, you are `alert`ing before anything is clicked. *edit:* yes, that's exactly it... so, what is the problem?

Comment: this is where i am stuck and this is what i am saying...i know i am asking to alert value of val to be shown by alert before val=$(this).index() assigns value to it.....it want that val should be assigned the val first, then a cookie of that val must be created, next time when user enters the page, checkCookie loads up and finds that cookie so user do not have to choose any of the options again....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys check this out...i made a new code and that did work for me...i am putting it here so that people seeking for events like me may find it helpful....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val,cookiee;
$(document).ready(function(e) {

            $('.nav a').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                 val=$(this).index();

                if(val==0){

                $('#hide_main').hide();
                $('.main_BSNS').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')


                    var value="BSNS"
                    var today = new Date();
                    var expire = new Date();
                    nDays=1;
                    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
                    document.cookie = escape(value) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();

                    }//if val==0 ends here

                else if(val==1){

                    $('#hide_main').hide();
                    $('.main_ACTNT').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')                                                

                    var value="ACTNT"
                    var today = new Date();
                    var expire = new Date();
                    nDays=1;
                    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
                    document.cookie = escape(value) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
                    }

                else if(val==2){

                    $('#hide_main').hide();
                    $('.main_devp').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')                                             

                    var value="APP"
                    var today = new Date();
                    var expire = new Date();
                    nDays=1;
                    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
                    document.cookie = escape(value) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();

                    }




            });
});
function checkCookie(){

cookiee=document.cookie;//assigning cookie value to var cookiee
var check_BSNS=cookiee.match(/BSNS/);//checking if cookie has word BSNS
var check_ACTNT=cookiee.match(/ACTNT/);//checking if cookie has word ACTNT
var check_APP=cookiee.match(/APP/);//checking if cookie has word BSNS

if(check_BSNS=="BSNS" && check_ACTNT==null && check_APP==null)//code to executed if cookie has BSNS
{
                $('#hide_main').hide();
                $('.main_BSNS').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')


    }

else if(check_BSNS==null && check_ACTNT=="ACTNT" && check_APP==null)//code to executed if cookie has ACTNT
{
            $('#hide_main').hide();
            $('.main_ACTNT').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')                                                


    }

else if(check_BSNS==null && check_ACTNT==null && check_APP=="APP")//code to executed if cookie has APP
{
            $('#hide_main').hide();
            $('.main_devp').animate({opacity:"show",height:"400px"},'slow')                                                     

    }





}
```

window.onload=checkCookie();// this code will loads the function checkCookie right after the window is opened...

Now this checkCookie() function will be called by body onload="checkCookie()"....i just put comments there to show the working of the co